# PHP: проблема с выводом ссылок пагинатора

Tags: php, пагинация

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

У меня есть класс пагинации. И всё бы хорошо, но, при изминении количества выводимых на страницу элементов, сбиватеся вид блока пагинации (так себе, сформулировал). В общем, если задано выводить по одной строке из БД, то всё хорошо — 1 … 3 4 **5** 6 7 … 20, но, если более одной, то получается вот так — 1 … 3 4 **5** 6 7 … (т. е. не отображается последняя страница или первая, если текущая ближе к концу). В чём может быть проблема?

Вот сам класс:

```
class Pagination
{
    private $max = INF; // 10
    private $route;
    private $index = '';
    private $current_page;
    private $total;
    private $limit;

    public function __construct($route, $total, $limit = 5) // 5
    {
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->total = $total;
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->amount = $this->amount();
        $this->setCurrentPage();
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $links = null;
        $limits = $this->limits();
        $html = '<ul>';
        for ($this->amount = null, $page = $limits[0]; $page <= $limits[1]; $page++) {
            if ($page == 1 or $page == $this->total or abs($page - $this->current_page) < 3) { // 3
                if ($page == $this->current_page) {
                    $links .= $this->amount = '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
                } else {
                    $links .= $this->amount = $this->generateHtml($page);
                }
            } else {
                if ($this->amount == '<li>...</li>' or $this->amount == null) {
                    $links .= $this->amount = null;
                } else {
                    $links .= $this->amount = '<li>...</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $links . '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }

    private function generateHtml($page, $text = null)
    {
        if (!$text) {
            $text = $page;
        }
    
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin') !== false) {
            $prefix = 'admin/';
        } else {
            $prefix = null;
        }
    
        return '<li><a href="/' . $prefix . $this->route['controller'] . '/' . $this->route['action'] . '/' . $page . '">' . $text . '</a></li>';
    }

    private function limits()
    {
        $left = $this->current_page - round($this->max / 2); // 2
        $start = $left > 0 ? $left : 1;
        if ($start + $this->max <= $this->amount) {
            $end = $start > 1 ? $start + $this->max : $this->max;
        } else {
            $end = $this->amount;
            $start = $this->amount - $this->max > 0 ? $this->amount - $this->max : 1;
        }
        return array($start, $end);
    }

    private function setCurrentPage()
    {
        if (isset($this->route['page'])) {
            $currentPage = $this->route['page'];
        } else {
            $currentPage = 1;
        }
        $this->current_page = $currentPage;
        if ($this->current_page > 0) {
            if ($this->current_page > $this->amount) {
                $this->current_page = $this->amount;
            }
        } else {
            $this->current_page = 1;
        }
    }

    private function amount()
    {
        return ceil($this->total / $this->limit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в этой строке:

Нужно заменить либо на `$page == $limits[1]` или пересмотреть использование свойства `amount`

```php
if ($page == 1 or $page == $this->total or abs($page - $this->current_page) < 3) { // 3
```

1. Свойство `total`, судя по конструктору, отвечает за общее количество записей, а не количество страниц страниц, поэтому условие `$page == $this->total` выполнится при условии одной записи на одной странице.
2. Свойство `index` не используется, зачем оно?
3. Конструктор занимается вычислением:

```php
$this->amount = $this->amount();
```

И в единственном публичном методе эти значения затираются

```php
$this->amount = null
```

4. Вот это условие проверяется каждый раз при вызове, а зачем?

```php
   if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin') !== false) {
            $prefix = 'admin/';
   }
```

Получилось незаконченное код-ревью, а ответ был в самом начале.

В результате получились следующие результаты:

Я установил `$total = 140, $limit = 10`. Все страницы сохраняются.
14 итераций:

| Итерация | Пагинация |
| --- | --- |
| #1: | 1 2 3 ... 14 |
| #2: | 1 2 3 4 ... 14 |
| #3: | 1 2 3 4 5 ... 14 |
| #4: | 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 14 |
| #5: | 1 ... 3 4 5 6 7 ... 14 |
| #6: | 1 ... 4 5 6 7 8 ... 14 |
| #7: | 1 ... 5 6 7 8 9 ... 14 |
| #8: | 1 ... 6 7 8 9 10 ... 14 |
| #9: | 1 ... 7 8 9 10 11 ... 14 |
| #10: | 1 ... 8 9 10 11 12 ... 14 |
| #11: | 1 ... 9 10 11 12 13 14 |
| #12: | 1 ... 10 11 12 13 14 |
| #13: | 1 ... 11 12 13 14 |
| #14: | 1 ... 12 13 14 |

Comment: если заменить на это, $page == $limits[1] то, действительно, отображается последняя страница, но, теряется первая: 6 7 8 9 10 … 14, нужно ведь, чтобы было так 1… 6 7 8 9 10 … 14 :)

Comment: Я установил `$total = 140, $limit = 10`. Все страницы сохраняются.
14 итераций:




#1:  1  2  3 ... 14 
#2:  1  2  3  4 ... 14 
#3:  1  2  3  4  5 ... 14 
#4:  1  2  3  4  5  6 ... 14 
#5:  1 ... 3  4  5  6  7 ... 14 
#6:  1 ... 4  5  6  7  8 ... 14 
#7:  1 ... 5  6  7  8  9 ... 14 
#8:  1 ... 6  7  8  9  10 ... 14 
#9:  1 ... 7  8  9  10  11 ... 14 
#10:  1 ... 8  9  10  11  12 ... 14 
#11:  1 ... 9  10  11  12  13  14 
#12:  1 ... 10  11  12  13  14 
#13:  1 ... 11  12  13  14 
#14:  1 ... 12  13  14

Comment: У меня total — 60, limit = 5, всё равно с левой стороны исчезают ссылки. Приведите пожалуйста итоговый код класса, который работает у вас

Comment: Вот так работает: `if ($page == $limits[0] or $page == $limits[1] or abs($page - $this->current_page) < 3) { // 3` :)